# Using ExceptionFilterAttribute in upgraded MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes, asp.net-mvc-migration

Is it possible to use ExceptionFilterAttribute in a project the was created with MVC2 and upgraded to MVC4?  It is not a Web API project, and I cannot seem to get the exception to catch using the ExceptionFilterAttribute.  Is there any way to make this happen or am I better off just sticking to inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute and implementing IExceptionFilter.  This is for an API section within our MVC project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC attributes and Web API attributes are not compatible.

MVC ones are of `System.Web.Mvc.Filter` type [1], while Web API  are of `System.Web.Http.Filters.Filter` type [2] - so you need to make sure you get your base class correct before trying to apply the attribute to Web API.

[1] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filter(v=vs.98).aspx

[2] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.filter(v=vs.108).aspx